# How to limit the character number in bracket using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i have this this text.

```
[If you purchased or upgraded RegexBuddy after 13 June 2007, you can download the latest version by ][typing in your email address and RegexBuddy user ID below.]
```

Right now the the open and close bracket indicate it is 100 and below characters (using javascript).

How do i prevent user from enter other words between the bracket that will make it more than 100 chars?

I dont want to prevent user from input anything, i just want to prevent the sentence in the bracket will not exceed 100 chars.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Quick 'n' dirty:

```
$(someElementOrSelector).keydown(function(e) {
    var bracket_start = $(this).text().indexOf('['),
        bracket_end = $(this).text().lastIndexOf(']');
    if((bracket_end - bracket_start) > 100) {
       e.preventDefault();
       return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: In his example he got two bracket pairs so would your code won't check there is more then 100 characters between the first `[` and the last `]` I don't think that what the OP wants. Not sure anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try to match 100 character in bracket if yu have a match you should display on alert or what ever is convenient to you.

```
if (myString.match(/\[.{100}[^\]]+\]/))
{
   alert('you have too many characters'); 
}
```

Comment: hi this code will not work if there is more than one open and close bracket. example:   [If you purchased or upgraded RegexBuddy after 13 June 2007, you can download the latest version by t][maximum]

Comment: @cyberfly: it should since it's a regexp.

Answer (score 0):

you can put a function on keypress event that count the length of the particular div, and then will check if that counter > 100 then will popup message will displayed and return false.

Thanks.